# How to determine remote link speed?

Tags: ethernet, network-speed, switch

I'm on a non-manageable switched 1 GbE network with mixed 100 MbE and 1 GbE hosts.

Is it possible to tell if a certain host has a certain link speed without looking at the status LEDs of the switch and without access to the hosts?

Answer (score 1):

If by 'no access', you mean 'no ip level access whatsoever', then no. If you merely mean 'without logging in', you could use SNMP. `IF-MIB::ifSpeed` is the metric to look for.

Comment: With no access I mean no ssh, no SNMP, no nothing. All I have is IP level access but I'm unable to install services on the hosts. I was hoping there was some kind of ICMP mechanism or something comparable to get interface information...

Comment: Well, you're looking at the wrong place. This site is for people who administer systems, sounds like you need to talk to your sysadmin instead.

Comment: I am the sysadmin... ;)

Comment: No, you're not. You can't install anything on the hosts, so you're not administering them.

Comment: ...they are certified embedded devices...

Comment: No way of installing software on them with out breaking certification.

Comment: Then file a feature request with your vendor :)